# rename many files automatic one time - ddmmyyyy.file to yyyymmdd.file

Tags: php, file, rename

I have 1500 files that are named with an incorrectly dateformat. I would like to rename them. Are there a tool that can do that? Otherwise a piece of php code.

File names are:
ddmmyyyy.xls (e.g. 15012010 for 15.th Jan 2010)

and I would like:
yyyymmdd.xls (e.g. 20100115.xls)

Any clue on how this can be done for 1500 files in one go?

BR. Anders

---

UPDATE:
Also tried the MP3TAG, that is suggested in one of the answers. It is a free tool and also did the job. It took a while to figure out how to use it. If you wanne try do this:

1. add xls (or other format) to the list of editable files in configuration
2. choose folder to load files AND mark files in the pane you want to edit
3. I clicked the "Convert - Quick" button. It is also possible to save schemaes for future use but I could not figure out how.
4. after clicking "convert - quick" choose "using regex" (only regex option)

And then you just add the info to process the renaming. In my case:

- field: _FILENAME
- from: ([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})
- to: $3-$2-$1

Now all files named 15012010.xls (ddmmyyyy.xls) will be named 2010-01-15.xls

Comment: As a precaution, be sure to make a backup of the files, before you attempt any of the solutions.

Comment: Will do :-)
Can never be said often enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start (untested, but you should get the idea).

```
$files = glob('your/folder/*.xls');

foreach($files as $file) {

    preg_match_all('/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})\.xls$/', basename($file), $matches);

    if ( ! $matches) continue;        

    $year = $matches[0][3];
    $month = $matches[0][2];
    $day = $matches[0][1];

    $newFilename = $year . $month . $day . '.xls'; 
    rename  ( $file, dirname($file) . '/' . $newFilename );

}
```

Comment: Regex should be `/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})\.xls$/i`, no?

Comment: Thanks. All files have been renamed succesfully.

Comment: Wouldn't this be dangerous if you had, say, files from 20th September 2001 and 20th January 2009 in the same folder to convert? (i.e. you'd attempt to rename one to a name that already exists and fail/overwrite). Better would probably be to an intermediate extension that isn't used in that folder, then a grand rename at the end...

Comment: @Damien - yeh, you could do all that, but if you knew your input files were good (and weren't going to overwrite anything) you could get away with this. This was meant to be a quick solution for a once off problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux machine with the files... you can use bash to do:

```
for f in *.xls; do
    mv $f "$(echo $f | cut -c4-8)$(echo $f | cut -c3,4)$(echo $f | cut -c1,2).xls"
done
```

Comment: +1.  Also notable, can be done with a Mac running Mac OS or a windows machine running Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

A tool that can perform filename pattern conversion is [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/).

Choose `convert` and then `filename - filename`.

I'm sure there's other tools out there too!

(This answer isn't really in the StackOverflow spirit but I think the OP isn't necessarily looking for an automated solution...)

Comment: The goal is not to convert XLS files... to XLS files but rename it.

Comment: Mp3tag is a free tool for batch renaming files by a file pattern (among other tools) which is what I believe the the goal was.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in the weekend and it worked just fine. Updated my question with a short quick-start guide.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [alex function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068332/rename-many-files-automatic-one-time-ddmmyyyy-file-to-yyyymmdd-file/2068368#2068368), but this one correctly adds the `.xls` extension.

```
foreach (glob('/path/to/your/*.xls') as $file)
{
    rename($file, dirname($file) . '/' . substr(basename($file), 4, 4) . substr(basename($file), 2, 2) . substr(basename($file), 0, 2) . '.xls');
}
```

Comment: Hey mine does add the .xls extension!

Comment: @alex: You edited it: `$newFilename = $year . $month . $day;` you only had this.

Comment: Sorry, yeh I did originally. I made quite a few edits because I forgot things!

Answer (score 0):

if you have bash

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for xls in [0-9]*.xls
do
    day=${xls:0:2}
    mth=${xls:3:2}
    yr=${xls:4:4}
    echo mv "$xls" "${yr}${mth}${day}.xls"
done
```

no need external tools.

Answer (score 0):

> File names are: ddmmyyyy.xls (e.g.
>   15012010 for 15.th Jan 2010)
>
> and I would like: yyyymmdd.xls (e.g.
>   20100115.xls)

Use this script.

```
# Script RenameYYYYMMDD.txt
var str dir, list, file, newname, dd, mm
lf -r -n "*.xls" $dir > $list
while ($list <> "")
do
    lex "1" $list > $file ; stex -p "^/^l[" $file > $newname ; chex "2]" $newname > $dd
    chex "2]" $newname > $mm ; sin "^.^l" ($mm+$dd) $newname > null
    system rename ("\""+$file+"\"") $newname
done
```

This script is in biterscripting ( http://www.biterscripting.com ). Test the script first in a test folder.

To test, save the script code in file "C:/Scripts/RenameYYYYMMDD.txt", and enter the following command.

```
script "C:/Scripts/RenameYYYYMMDD.txt" dir("C:/path/to/test folder")
```

This command will rename all files ddmmyyyy.xls under directory "C:/path/to/test folder" to yyyymmdd.xls.